# Can you use Nest for devices not directly related to smarthome?

Tags: bluetooth, nest-api

Our company creates activity trackers for the family (like the Fitbit or Up by Jawbone), but that only track steps (there is no sleep feature or anything).

I was wondering if it was possible and allowed to use the Nest as a central HUB to sync via bluetooth the physical activity of all family members entering the house and send the data to a server or an app, even if it doesn't impact the thermostats.

Nest documentation doesn't seem to mention that aspect, so I wasn't sure if it was possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the Nest has Bluetooth hardware. And the purpose of the API is to enable control and reading of Nest specific data.

Comment: Correct, the Nest API only works via HTTPS and WebSockets to the Nest Cloud. There is no support for local networking via any protocol.